# mean population growth of a simple birth process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, birth-death-process

I'm working with the book "Markov Chains" by J.R.Norris, and I'm stuck on the following passage. Specifically, could someone explain why we have that
$$E[X_t | T=s] = 2\mu(t-s)$$ here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At time $T$ the number of individuals grows from 1 to 2. So given $T=s$, the conditional expectation of the number of individuals at time $t$ will be $2\mu(t-s)$, twice the expectation arising from one individual after $t-s$ time units.